# Evaluating $\int^\infty _1 \frac{1}{x^4 \sqrt{x^2 + 3} } dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was evaluating

> $$\int^\infty _1 \frac{1}{x^4 \sqrt{x^2 + 3} } dx$$

**My work:**

I see that in the denominator, there is the radical $\sqrt{x^2 + 3}$. This reminds me of the trigonometric substitution $\sqrt{u^2 + a^2}$ and letting 
$ u = a \tan \theta$. With this in mind: I let $x = \sqrt{3} \tan \theta$ .Moving on, $dx = \sqrt{3} (\sec \theta )^2 $. And.....if $\theta$ is an 
acute angle, we see in the illustration below that...

[image: UTOG2.png]

$\tan \theta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$

Then...getting the equivalent form of $\sqrt{x^2 + 3}$ in terms of $\theta$:

$$\sqrt{x^2 + 3}$$
$$ =\sqrt{(\sqrt{3} \tan \theta)^2 + 3}$$
$$= \sqrt{3(\tan \theta)^2 + 3}$$
$$= \sqrt{3((\tan \theta)^2 + 1)}$$
$$= \sqrt{3} \sqrt{(\sec \theta)^2} $$
$$\sqrt{x^2 + 3} = \sqrt{3} \sec \theta $$

Getting the equivalent form of $x^4$ in terms of $\theta$:

$$x^4 = (\sqrt{3} \tan \theta)^4$$
$$ = 9 (\tan \theta)^4 $$

Getting the equivalent form of $dx$ in terms of $\theta$:

$$dx = \sqrt{3} (\sec \theta )^2 d\theta$$

Substituting these equivalent expressions to the integral above, we get:

$$\int \frac{1}{x^4 \sqrt{x^2 + 3} } dx = \int \frac{1}{9 (\tan \theta)^4 \sqrt{3} \sec \theta } \sqrt{3} (\sec \theta )^2 d\theta$$
$$ = \int \frac{1}{9 \sqrt{3} (\tan \theta)^4 \sec \theta } \sqrt{3} (\sec \theta )^2 d\theta$$
$$ = \int \frac{\sqrt{3} (\sec \theta )^2}{9 \sqrt{3} (\tan \theta)^4 \sec \theta } d\theta$$
$$ = \int \frac{\sec \theta}{9  (\tan \theta)^4 } d\theta$$
$$ = \int \frac{\sec \theta}{9  ((\tan \theta)^2)^2   } d\theta$$
$$ = \int \frac{\sec \theta}{9  ((\sec \theta)^2 - 1 )^2   } d\theta$$
$$ = \int \frac{\sec \theta}{9  ((\sec \theta)^2 - 1 )^2   } d\theta$$
$$ = \frac{1}{9}\int \frac{\sec \theta}{((\sec \theta)^2 - 1 )^2   } d\theta$$
$$\int \frac{1}{x^4 \sqrt{x^2 + 3} } dx = \frac{1}{9}\int \frac{\sec \theta}{ (\sec \theta)^4 -2(\sec \theta)^2 +1 } d\theta$$

My problem is....I don't know how to evaluate $\frac{1}{9}\int \frac{\sec \theta}{ (\sec \theta)^4 -2(\sec \theta)^2 +1 } d\theta$.

I can't go forward. I'm stuck. How to evaluate $\int^\infty _1 \frac{1}{x^4 \sqrt{x^2 + 3} } dx$ properly?

Answer (score 3):

By letting $x=1/t$ and by integration by parts, we get
\begin{align*}
\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4 \sqrt{x^2 + 3} } dx
&=
\int_0^1\frac{t^3}{\sqrt{3t^2 + 1}}\,dt=
\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1t^2\frac{d(\sqrt{3t^2 + 1})}{dt}\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\left[t^2\sqrt{3t^2 + 1}\right]_0^1-
\frac{2}{3}\int_0^1 t\sqrt{3t^2 + 1} dt\\
&=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{27}\left[(3t^2 + 1)^{3/2}\right]_0^1=\frac{4}{27}.
\end{align*}

Comment: @Palautot Ka Any further doubt?

Comment: @Donald Splutterwit Thanks!

Comment: I was supposed to only use trigonometric substitution....but your approach (a reciprocal substitution) is great..I never thought I could apply it to the integral aboveXD

Comment: @PalautotKa I am glad that you appreciate my approach.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{\sec t}{\tan^4t}=\dfrac{\cos^3t}{\sin^2t}=\dfrac{(1-\sin^2t)\cos t}{\sin^2t}$$

Set $\sin t=u$

OR directly, $u=\dfrac{\tan t}{\sec t}=\dfrac x{\sqrt{x^2+3}}$ assuming $0\le t<\dfrac\pi2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You have done a good substitution so here you are
$$\int \frac{1}{9 (\tan \theta)^4 \sqrt{3} \sec \theta } \sqrt{3} (\sec \theta )^2 d\theta=\dfrac{1}{9}\int\dfrac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin^4\theta}\cos\theta\,d\theta=\dfrac{1}{9}\int\dfrac{1-\sin^2\theta}{\sin^4\theta}\cos\theta\,d\theta$$
now let $\sin\theta=u$ and continue!

Comment: Right! thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate by parts
\begin{align}\int^\infty _1 \frac{1}{x^4 \sqrt{x^2 + 3} } dx
=&\ \frac19\int_1^\infty \frac1{x^2+3}\ d\bigg[\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}}{-x}\bigg)^3\ \bigg]\\
=&\ \frac29+\frac2{27}\int_1^\infty \ d\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 3}}{x}\bigg)=\frac4{27}\\
\end{align}

Comment: It is always a mystery how you think to consider things like $(\sqrt{x^2+3}/x)^3$

Comment: @FShrike - I keep in mind thing like $\left(\frac{\sqrt{t^2 +1}}{t}\right)’=-\frac1{t^2\sqrt{1+t^2}}$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4 \sqrt{x^2+3}} & =\int_0^1 \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{3 x^2+1}} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 \frac{x\left(3 x^2+1-1\right)}{\sqrt{3 x^2+1}} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{18} \int_0^1\left(\sqrt{3 x^2+1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3 x^2+1}} \right)d\left(3 x^2-1\right)\\
& =\frac{1}{18}\left[\frac{2}{3}\left(3 x^2+1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}-2 \sqrt{3 x^2+1}\right]_0^1 \\
& =\frac{4}{27}
\end{aligned}
$$